Small-ish (sub-centimeter) latching/locking connector for multiple (~4) isolated wires not bundled into the same plug
This is more mechanics than electronics but I didn't find a StackExchange site that would be better fit for it, so here goes:
I'm wondering if there is a type of "standard" connector that fulfills these requirements:

The total socket/plug cross section is no larger than around 1 cm², maybe 2. Ideally, it fits inside a 1 cm × 1 cm square.
The socket has "slots" for at least 4 (but not much more than that) connections isolated from each other.
These slots each take a plug that is designed to terminate a single wire (i.e. the socket doesn't need a mechanically fused plug housing all connections).
There is a locking or latching mechanism that prevents plugs from sliding out which is at least as mechanically stable as a typical USB socket-plug connection. It's fine if this mechanism only works properly with all plugs connected.
(Dis)connecting is possible without any tools (so screw terminals are out).

So basically something a lot like single-pin Dupont plugs combined with a 2×2 socket:


But much more mechanically stable when connected.

Have you tried identiconn? https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?Q=

This sounds an awful lot like product recommendations, which technically is considered off topic here, although its not the most stringently enforced rule, so you might be lucky and get answers. Just wanted to let you know.

What do you mean "cap"? To terminate, end in a connector/pin/housing? What degree of "isolation" are you looking for? Current ratings?  || As mentioned above, this may be closed as a "shopping" question; I don't feel strongly about it myself, but I would ask voters to comment their reasoning, or if such an issue is curable, to propose edits to address it.

You are basically just describing almost any wire to board connector with latch. There are hundreds. As @TimWilliams asks, to really narrow down you need to start listing the hard technical requirements.

@winny Will have a look now, thank you!

@MrGerber I agree and I was going to ask on hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but apparently they forbid questions asking for "small parts" like this rather than complex pieces of hardware. I wish there was partsrecs.stackexchange.com for such things.

The problem is that if you can establish the technical requirements, the job is basically to put them into a parametric search at your preferred component vendor, so really not something a Q/A site can help you with. On the other hand, if you don't know what you want, there isn't anything a Q/A site can do either. Maybe there is some general value to be had with a question about how to establish the relevant specs for a connector, but it might be too broad as well.

@TimWilliams Yes, I meant terminating a wire so it ends with a plug. I've edited the questoin to hopefully make that more clear. No specific requirements as to ratings etc., whatever is typical for something of that size will almost definitely be fine.

@MrGerber All right, feel free to close it then. And thanks for the help in the comments!

@smheidrich It's not my desicion to make, I just tried to give a reasoning for why questions like these often are considered less relevant for a Q/A site.

Anyway, I support the suggestion from @winny of looking at connectorbook, which most likely is the most comprehensive overview of what connectors are available out there.

A 2.5 mm pitch terminal block with lever terminals (to meet the tool-free requirement)?

I see quick disconnect terminals used together in automotive plugs, but these connectors also come in singles  with spring or lever operated retention. one of the smaller sizes would probably fit your requirement

I consider this question very acceptable. Some will not. I've been thinking about the boundaries for "shopping questions". Some groups are far less rigorous than close voters here often are. I consider that a query re components that meet a need (including eg re integrated circuits  that have specific part number recommendations) are NOT 'shopping questions' as intended by the original spirit of the description. Knowing that an Amphenol abcd1234 connector meets a need is significantly different than "where can I buy an XXX" OR "where can I buy an assembly that I can use as is?" ||

Thanks for posting this perfect question, new user.  It's ideal for a site like this where (as you can see) you can get actual on-the-ground expert advice from people very familiar with the issues, in practice.

You didn't say whether they are electrically separate circuits or all the same circuit.
If separate circuits:
What about a multi-circuit lever splice?
https://www.adafruit.com/product/5617

{Source: Adafruit}
Or, what about Quick spring terminal blocks? (My site)

{Source: eBay}
Or, what about a RAST 5 male connector with latching quick-connect female disconnects?

{Source: Lumberg 3647}

{Source: Digigey TE 790319-3}

If all the same circuit:
What about standard lever splices?
https://www.digikey.com/short/v31htm4b

{Source: Digikey}
Or even, what about Terminal Junction Systems?
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/terminal-junction-systems/422

{Amphenol SIME0412SN, source: Digikey}

One of these will work, thank you! :-) And great site!
